# How to access virtual keyboard suggestions with javascript the same way i could using a <datalist> in html

Tags: javascript, html, virtual-keyboard, html-datalist

I have a rather compact static UI made in **JS + Jquery/HTML/CSS**.

I **need** to make a a text input with suggestions, which **so far i succeeded however it misses one thing**. That is the suggestions (or autocomplete) on phones, which could be done if i uses a **<datalist>** html tag.

I don't have any professional testing environment that would allow me to test on most browsers how my UI is rendered. Hence I'm using only <div> as I know they will render almost always the same on any browsers. Including not using **<datalist>** (note i may be wrong but i believe <datalist> is like <select> with a rendering a styling completely dependent on browsers especially because it relies on <options> tags which i already had trouble with and Apple products because <options> weren't rendering at all (and i don't own any Apple product to debug myself).

**Therefore** I thought of directly telling the keyboard maybe with the experimental [VirtualKeyboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VirtualKeyboard_API) but i couldn't find anything.

And i don't have any further guesses, if anyone has any idea, lead or advice then many thanks

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but using only div elements in order to ensure cross-browser consistency is a heavy overcorrection. Semantic HTML elements are a critical part of usability and accessibility. You can use CSS [normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or [reset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reset_style_sheet) to make elements more consistently styled.

Comment: *"I don't have any professional testing environment that would allow me to test on most browsers how my UI is rendered."* ... You can install as many browsers on your computers to test on. You can also weigh whether to target modern browsers and not worry too much about outdated browsers/versions, if feasible for the project.

Comment: For user-agent styles that are device specific (such as the way iOS devices handle `select` dropdowns) it's important to realize that those users are used to seeing things that way. Efforts you make to make your UI totally consistent across different browsers will result in what feels like an inconsistent experience for users, since your UI will behave differently than what they're used to. Apple products absolutely support `option` tags if they're used correctly.

Comment: I wouldn't disagree with anything said, I just want to point out that I do an application rather than a webpage so HTML semantics are more a trouble than anything and user-agent styles actually breaks the styling coherence of the application. CSS reset is actually a good idea thanks. I cannot install as many browsers i want, modern safari isn't available for non-apple products, Opera-GX is strictly windows, only to cite two. also yes they do support `option` but I use it wrong on purpose (i wasn't aware of CSS reset)